How to recover which partition is the Windows 10 EFI bootloader is looking for?
In order to install Linux alongside Windows 10, I've done the following procedure:

Boot into Windows 10 (on a NVMe SSD, UEFI mode), "Shrink volume" to a smaller size
Reboot into a Linux LiveCD
fdisk /dev/nvme0n1 (there were four partitions: "EFI System", "Microsoft reserved", "Microsoft basic data" and "Windows recovery environment")
Remove the third partition, recreate it with a smaller size: "new partition", "type - 11"
Create two more partitions for Linux in the freed space
ntfsresize the Windows partition to fill the space allocated for it (this went with no problems)

Then I've tried to boot back into Windows, and instead of a normal boot, now I automatically boot into the "Automatic repair" environment.
I've attempted to recreate the Windows EFI bootloader, but diskpart said that there are no disks available - i.e. it does not seem to have the driver for the NVMe.
Problem 1: how can I find out what exactly is the problem preventing the boot?
Problem 2: I can guess what it is - probably the partition GUID must have changed when I've recreated the partition. And it didn't occur to me to write it down in advance. (I'm not very familiar with EFI yet, and this was not an issue with MBR.) I can fix the partition GUID if I know which one do I need, but how can I find out which GUID is the bootloader looking for? I see many GUID-like looking things in BCD and BCD.LOG, and I think one of them must be the partition to look for, but which one of them is "the partition the bootloader is looking for"?

The recommended way is to shrink a partition, leaving free space for the installer, and let the Linux installer create the disk structures needed in the free space. See this guide for Ubuntu, for example: https://gcore.com/learning/dual-boot-ubuntu-windows-setup/ Before starting, you should have made a disk image, which you can restore now.

As above ^^^. Also don't forget to disable Windows Fast Startup "feature" , a must when dual-booting.

What method have you used to backup and restore the contents of the Windows partition?

I have not made a backup since I merely resized a partition, which was supposed to be a non-destructive operation. All the data is still there, except for the UUID. I've shrunk the partition a little excessively using "Windows Disk Management", then repartitioned it with fdisk to the exact size I want, then expanded the filesystem to fill the new partition size. I've omitted unrelated stuff - I'm not using the installer, I'm bootstrapping Linux manually; the problem is that apparently the bootloader can't find the "old" partition by its UUID...

Since you get to boot into "Automatic repair", you're already booting into
Windows. The problem is that Windows was damaged by this unrecommended
method that you used.
It's a bad idea to use Linux for resizing a Windows system partition,
because it might reduce the partition too much.
Using the Windows Disk Management for that is much safer because it
won't damage the partition.
If you didn't take a disk image backup before doing this, you now need
to reinstall Windows.

Worse case scenario it needs repair that can be done by booting Windows installation media. Reinstalling Windows is not necessary.

@ChanganAuto: Which repair? It's not Startup Repair because it's booting so startup is OK. It's not Repair Install since that can only be done from inside Windows.

The repair it needs probably can be done by itself if the OP let it finish. If not then there are tools for advanced repair in the installation media.

@ChanganAuto: Advanced repair options include : Startup Repair, Startup Settings, Command Prompt, Uninstall Updates, UEFI Firmware Settings, System Restore. Which one will help here?

System Restore. And while you're correct about it booting already, Startup Repair can also detect and update the GUID of all the system partitions, including recovery which was the one the OP messed with, and then update the efi stanza accordingly. Any or all of the options are the logical thing to do before the nuclear option.

@ChanganAuto: System Restore will restore Windows files, which are very likely already there. Any missing files were located at the end of the partition before it got truncated. Windows is the first to be installed on a new partition, so it's installed at the beginning. If Windows files did exist in the truncated part, then the poster truncated the partition too much, so likely it's now just too small to hold the old installation (but I don't believe in this possibility).

A likelier possibility is that backuping and restoring the partition was done incorrectly, so Windows is now effectively destroyed. It's also unsure that System Restore was enabled at all.

I'm booting into Windows RE, aka "Windows Installation media", which does not have the NVMe driver, so I couldn't update the EFI with the new partition GUID. It fails to autorepair anything, obviously. I've shrunk the system partition a little excessively using "Windows Disk Management", then repartitioned it with fdisk to the exact size I want, then expanded the filesystem to fill the new partition size. The problem is that the bootloader can't find the "old" partition by its UUID, so can I find out which UUID is it looking for? Or update it in the bootloader manually with a hex editor?

You can do without this and just update GRUB. A useful tool would be Super Grub2 disk. However, if Windows doesn't boot it will be hard to fix.
